# Speaker Diarization support in Google Speech API

Tags: google-cloud-speech

Is Google Cloud Speech API support speaker Diarization? as like Watson ?
If so what the steps to get the transcript with speaker labled?

More Info:
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/watson/2016/12/look-whos-talking-ibm-debuts-watson-speech-text-speaker-diarization-beta/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has introduced this feature and as on writing it's on BETA.

More info - https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/

Comment: Hello @Gunarathinam, Can you please check below question, Have you face such type of issue during this feature development?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59437181/speaker-diarization-from-audio-file-android

Comment: sadly, it sucks. missing speaker entirely and cross word to another speaker

Answer (score 1):

Per the group discussion at [Recording, Splitting Audio for Transcribing Two People Conversation using Google Speech API](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-speech-discuss/neSEDMBP62w), it looks that you'll have to use the [speaker diarization libraries](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Speaker_diarisation) for your use case.